# Staking for Ram: burden on developers or users?

Tags: ram

When I'm setting up an application, do I have the option of making use of the Ram the user have or would I have to stake ram for the user?

What if some users have staked for ram and some have not?

Answer (score 2):

Your contract picks. `multi_index`'s `emplace` and `modify` functions have a `payer` argument that controls this. If you make the user pay and they don't have enough ram available, then the transaction will fail.

Comment: Can it be dynamic? if the user already has ram then make him pay, if not then the application will pay for him.

Comment: Yeah it can be dynamic as the payer would be specified when creating the actions, so if a user presses a button to do X you can prompt for Scatter to do the transactions specifying them as the payer, or, compose an action which specifies you (website/service) as the payer signed by both you and your user.