# do i still need to pay after deployed an eos contract

Tags: smart-contract, resources

I have deployed a contract. and I am confused about the fees:

Do I still need to pay for resources such as RAM and CPU for actions like `emplace` and `modify` after I deployed a contract? Or can I just let it go and let the players to deal with the RAM things?

Comment: No need to excuse yourself for being new :-)

Could you please tidy up your question? You can structure your question with bold headers like "Background", "Question", "Update",.. but usually not for several sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on code if you have set ram payer for multi_indexed table as self then you need to pay for that ram(whenever emplace implemented, No RAM for modifying) and if  you have set players as RAM payer then you don't need to pay for RAM.

For example in code

in this case you became payer of RAM.

```
orders.emplace( self, [&]( auto& o ) {
  o.id = 1;
  o.expiration = 300;
  o.owner = N(dan);
});
```

in this case player will become payer of RAM.

```
orders.emplace(_user , [&]( auto& o ) {
  o.id = 1;
  o.expiration = 300;
  o.owner = N(dan);
});
```

Comment: thanks! 
thanks! one more question, here is what i think:
i can initial like this [ gameTable(receiver,receiver.value) ]   
when some player calling the function transfer, i can redefine the payer like:
```
gameTable.emplace(from, [&](auto &p) {
                p.key = _currentbets.available_primary_key();
                ...
            });
```
 im i right ?

Comment: @Mr.Y It is not true that the scope of the table defines who is paying RAM. It is about the payer argument in emplace, modify methods. See here: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/594/staking-for-ram-burden-on-developers-or-users/609#609

Comment: edited my answer and this is from eos's official doc

Comment: @friedger Scope has nothing to do with RAM payments, see https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/3534/scope-in-the-get-table-command

Comment: @PhillipHamnett-EOS42 This is what I wanted to say. The payer argument is the relevant part.