# scope in the get table command

Tags: cleos, table

What is the meaning of scope argument in the get table command?

For example, in the todo_contract, (https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-get-table)

we have

cleos --wallet-url http://wallet:5555 -u http://server:7777 get table mynewaccount **todo** todos

The scope is **todo**.
I just wonder where todo comes from.

One more question is how to display the rows entirely.

The get table command shows only 10 rows.

At the end, I have

```
  "more": true
}
```

How can I see the rest of the rows?

Comment: try `cleos --wallet-url http://wallet:5555 -u http://server:7777 get table mynewaccount mynewaccount todos`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Meaning of scope

You can just make up a scope as you go along. As a general rule there are 3 ways to use the scope:

Globally - all table entries are kept in one scope (usually with the name of the contract)

```
cleos get table censuscensus global population
```

Groups - All table entries that are similar in some way share the same scope

```
cleos get table censuscensus male population
```

Individual - Each entry has its own scope (usually used to obfuscate or have quick access)

```
cleos get table censuscensus phillhamnett population
```

## Seeing all table rows

To see all table rows, just add `-l -1` (minus el, minus one) somewhere after `get table`.

## Within smart contract

Lets say you have a typedef set up in a smart contract for a `multi_index` array.

```
typedef eosio::multi_index< eosio::name("censuscensus"), struct_for_table_goes_here > census_table;
```

You can set a scope when you initialize the `census_table`:

```
census_table global_table(get_self(), eosio::name("global").value);
census_table male_table(get_self(), eosio::name("male").value);
census_table individual_table(get_self(), eosio::name("phillhamnett").value);
```

You don't need to do anything else to start using the table with the scope other than initialize it as shown above

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Then, the problem is how we can set the scope for a given table.

At least in the todo_contract example, there is no step to set or configure the scope "todo".

It seems that I can use any string instead of todo when I use the "get table" command.

Comment: I will update my answer to give more examples within a smart contract.

Comment: No problem. If my answer solves your question, you should upvote it and choose "accept answer" in order to help other people in the future.

Comment: I also added a bit that shows how to get more than 10 rows from the table

Comment: Got `no known conversion from 'eosio::name' to 'uint64_t'` and after looking at the tictactoe example I added `.value`, ie. `eosio::name("global").value`

Comment: Thanks I fixed my example